# Unable to find an element using webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to locate a tab which is a png image. I have the source of the tab. But I have tried the follwoing options:

1)

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("x", "a"));
String src = image.getAttribute("src"); 
src.contains("x.png");
```

2)

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.name("x"));
```

I'm unable to do find it.its not a hidden element as well...any inputs???? would be much appreciated...

Comment: Why are you calling `By.id` with 2 arguments when it only takes 1? What does the source of the tab look like?

Comment: ^ What he said. ^ ... `By.id()` only takes a single argument, the code above also does not use `src.contains()` in any way. You can also get it in a single line `By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'x.png')]")`. Have you tried [implicit](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) or [explicit](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) [wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits)? It's to most common solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way...

When i have image tags of this type and think id "Size50" is unique

```
<img id="Size50" src="http://sp2010-sa/talk/harold/Photos/_t/Profile_jpg.jpg"/>
```

Selenium will search in this way...

> WebElement
>   image=Driver.findElement(By.TagName("img")).findElement(By.id("Size50"));

The above code, first searches for all Image Tags and later within Image tags it will search for a Tag with unique ID  "Size50".

if the Id "Size50" is unique on the page then we can directly write the following

```
WebElement image=Driver.findElement(By.id("Size50"));
```